# Calculating chance of certain score in golf

Tags: probability, distributions, combinatorics

Im trying to calculate the probability of getting a certain scores on a given golf course when i know the average score the player gets on each hole. I also know the distribution of eagle birdie par bogey etc on each hole. How can i find the chance of scoring for exampel even par or 2 under par. There is a large number of combinations that result in each final score, so I dont even know where to begin. Can anyone help me?

Exampel of the data i have: Hole 1: Eagle: 1 Birdie: 12 Par: 33 bogey: 17 double bogey: 5

I have this data for all holes.

The original question a wanted to answer was if there was a bigger change of getting a -10 score with or witout an Eagle, but I ran into the above problem on the way.

Comment: You have to make strong, likely false, assumptions to obtain an answer.  One of them would be that on any given day a player's performance on each hole is independent of their performance on all other holes.  This is not plausible, because common factors (weather, physical condition, and so on) surely influence the performance in similar ways on all holes. Why not just classify every game in terms of total scores and whether an eagle occurred and analyze that dataset?  You would likely get more credible answers.